# Django ImageField can not change image file correctly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I use ImageField to store user's avatar, here is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    mugshot = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_mugshot_path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.mugshot:
            avatar = Avatar(rows=10, columns=10)
            image_byte_array = avatar.get_image(string=self.username,
                                                width=480,
                                                height=480,
                                                pad=10)
            self.mugshot.save('default_mugshot.png', ContentFile(image_byte_array), save=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When user sign up, this would create a default mugshot for him/her. The expected behavior is when user update their own mugshot, the default mugshot would be deleted. So I write the form and view like this:

```
class MugshotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('mugshot',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MugshotChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = MugshotForm
    template_name = 'users/mugshot_change.html'
    success_url = '/users/profile'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.has_changed():
            self.object.mugshot.delete(save=False)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    # TODO: Can't update mugshot correctly
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

But the real behavior is when updating the mugshot, the old mugshot would be deleted but the new one doesn't associated to model. It always create a new default mugshot for user.

What's wrong in codes? Thank you for you help!

Comment: I found the reason. form.instance and self.object are the some instance of user model, so I change the get_object method: return user= User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)